# Rails: Using Fog (paperclip) with Bluemix Object Storage v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openstack, ibm-cloud, fog, openstack-swift

I'm trying to use Bluemix Object Storage for storing some user content (images).
It runs Openstack Swift.

According to the [bluemix guide](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/index.html) it supports Keystone V2 authentication in an [unbound context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838114/bluemix-object-storage-whats-the-difference-between-bound-and-unbound-con) or Keystone v3 in a bound context.
Since my main app is not in the same Bluemix environment, I prefer to use unbound, but can also use bound via a dummy app.

According to some release notes for the Fog gem and the fog source code, both auth methods are supported. I'm using Fog 1.31.0.

Using the unbound method, I get the following credentials after creating the Bluemix service. All values are slightly changed for privacy reasons.

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "auth_url": "https://identity.open.softlayer.com",
    "project": "object_storage_af31119c",
    "projectId": "82e592b46bb84232370f9657fec2b576",
    "region": "dallas",
    "userId": "02faa40ff3f342faaafdty1a75bd901a",
    "username": "user_28uigjab0a2ef799eb5280c786a2ff503c978aaf",
    "password": "V3i~]oYU8/UMNvVm",
    "domainId": "3f160e53e6114a748a34724005a458ea",
    "domainName": "779543"
  }
}
```

The fog openstack docs contain [this](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/openstack/docs/storage.md) configuration example:

```
  service = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider            => 'OpenStack',   # OpenStack Fog provider
  :openstack_username  => USERNAME,      # Your OpenStack Username
  :openstack_api_key   => PASSWORD,      # Your OpenStack Password
  :openstack_auth_url  => 'http://YOUR_OPENSTACK_ENDPOINT:PORT/v2.0/tokens'
})
```

I filled my credentials and used https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v2.0/tokens as the auth_url.
This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught exception: Expected([200, 204]) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
excon.error.response
:body => "{\"error\": {\"message\": \"The request you have made requires 
authentication.\", \"code\": 401, \"title\": \"Unauthorized \"}}"

:headers => {
"Content-Length" => "114"
"Content-Type"   => "application/json"
"Date"           => "Fri, 06 Nov 2015 15:08:55 GMT"
"Server"         => "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5"
"Vary"           => "X-Auth-Token"
"WWW-Authenticate"       => "Keystone uri=\"https://identity.open.softlayer.com\""
"x-openstack-request-id" => "req-2f68188e-2a9e-45ad-ae18-289ac88b78ae" }
:local_address => "10.0.2.15"
:local_port    => 59407
:reason_phrase => "Unauthorized"
:remote_ip     => "198.23.119.11"
:status        => 401
:status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n"

/home/startupdeltadev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.45.3/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in `response_call'
/home/startupdeltadev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.45.3/lib/excon/middlewares/response_parser.rb:8:in `response_call'
/home/startupdeltadev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.45.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:372:in `response'
/home/startupdeltadev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/excon-0.45.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:236:in `request'
/home/startupdeltadev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-core-1.31.1/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:81:in `request'
/home/startupdeltadev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.31.0/lib/fog/openstack/core.rb:331:in `retrieve_tokens_v2'
```

Apparently, my credentials are not sent correctly. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Your Openstack user belongs to the '779543' domain.  The Identity (Keystone) v3 API supports domains.  I can't find any good examples on how to use Keystone v3 with Fog.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [Bluemix OpenStack Swift](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/#/resources/appGuid=bd1f7daf-6b65-4a07-ba1f-e948c4fd5609&orgGuid=542bf028-20f0-4c09-9648-be04afb4cbcc&spaceGuid=53422a2d-1b91-422e-943c-eb273a0b2ffe&serviceGuid=32ede2ad-796a-4adc-adc4-439d6ef940ec&cloudOEPaneId=resources)

> OpenStack Identity (Keystone) v2
>
> The v2 token request is a POST request to
>   https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v2.0/tokens as shown in the
>   following curl command:

```
curl -i \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '
{
    "auth": {
      "tenantId": "0f47b41b06d047f9aae3b33f1db061ed",
      "passwordCredentials": {
        "userId": "ad78b2a3f843466988afd077731c61fc",
        "password": "K/jyIi2jR=1?D.TP "
    }
}
}' \
https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v2.0/tokens ; echo
```

> Note: This request method is not documented on the OpenStack Identity
>   v2 website. **You cannot use tenantName and username**.

Fog::OpenStack (and many other libraries) uses **username** instead of **userId**

You should use **OpenStack Identity (Keystone) v3** in this way:

```
storage = Fog::OpenStack.new({
  :provider                 => 'OpenStack',
  :openstack_auth_url       => credentials['auth_url'],
  :openstack_api_key        => credentials['password'],
  :openstack_project_id     => credentials['projectId'],        
  :openstack_username       => credentials['username'],
  :openstack_domain_name    => credentials['domainName'],#required if you use :openstack_username (otherwise set :openstack_userid)
  :openstack_region         => credentials['region']
})
```